# How to build a dataframe column via pandas groupby or similar techniques?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find a pandas solution for the following problem (the dataframe is very long in reality, therefore performance really is an important topic):

I have an input dataframe df and need to build a new dataframe dfNew, where I need to derive the output in column 'rs' from the values of the other columns.

And the needed logics is the following:

- `t` is always increasing steadily from 0 to its maximum value. Afterwards its starts again with 0.
- whenever we are in the range from `t` = 0 and the next upcoming `pt` = 'X' (including), the value of column `td` should be taken for the result column `rs`, else the value of column `md` should be taken for column `rs`.

**How would a pandas based solution to derive `rs` from the other columns look like?**

```
td = ['td0','td1','td2','td3','td4','td5','td6','td7','td8','td9','td10','td11','td12']
md = ['md0','md1','md2','md3','md4','md5','md6','md7','md8','md9','md10','md11','md12']
t =  [   0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   4 ,   5 ,    0 ,    1 ,    2 ]
pt = [  'n',  'n',  'X',  'n',  'n',  'n',  'n',  'X',  'n',  'n',   'n',   'X',   'n']
df = pd.DataFrame({'td': td, 'md': md, 't': t, 'pt': pt}, columns=['td', 'md', 't', 'pt'])
df
      td    md  t pt
0    td0   md0  0  n
1    td1   md1  1  n
2    td2   md2  2  X
3    td3   md3  3  n
4    td4   md4  0  n
5    td5   md5  1  n
6    td6   md6  2  n
7    td7   md7  3  X
8    td8   md8  4  n
9    td9   md9  5  n
10  td10  md10  0  n
11  td11  md11  1  X
12  td12  md12  2  n  
dfNew
      td    md  t pt    rs
0    td0   md0  0  n   td0
1    td1   md1  1  n   td1
2    td2   md2  2  X   td2
3    td3   md3  3  n   md3
4    td4   md4  0  n   td4
5    td5   md5  1  n   td5
6    td6   md6  2  n   td6
7    td7   md7  3  X   td7
8    td8   md8  4  n   md8
9    td9   md9  5  n   md9
10  td10  md10  0  n  td10
11  td11  md11  1  X  td11
12  td12  md12  2  n  md12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take with `groupby` and `cumsum`

```
# df.t.eq(0).cumsum() marks the range of t
# similarly x.shift().eq('X').cumsum() marks the X range
pt_range = (df.groupby(df.t.eq(0).cumsum())
                  .pt.apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq('X').cumsum()))

df['rs'] = np.where(pt_range, df.md, df.td)
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+-------+----+-----+------+
|     | td    | md    | t  | pt  | rs   |
+-----+-------+-------+----+-----+------+
|  0  | td0   | md0   | 0  | n   | td0  |
|  1  | td1   | md1   | 1  | n   | td1  |
|  2  | td2   | md2   | 2  | X   | td2  |
|  3  | td3   | md3   | 3  | n   | md3  |
|  4  | td4   | md4   | 0  | n   | td4  |
|  5  | td5   | md5   | 1  | n   | td5  |
|  6  | td6   | md6   | 2  | n   | td6  |
|  7  | td7   | md7   | 3  | X   | td7  |
|  8  | td8   | md8   | 4  | n   | md8  |
|  9  | td9   | md9   | 5  | n   | md9  |
| 10  | td10  | md10  | 0  | n   | td10 |
| 11  | td11  | md11  | 1  | X   | td11 |
| 12  | td12  | md12  | 2  | n   | md12 |
+-----+-------+-------+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: This looks like a genious work to me. Honestly :-) But unfortunately, I am not yet able to understand, how the `groupby` and `apply(lambda...` work together. Do you see any possibility to explain this a little bit?

Comment: `groupby` gathers all the record sharing the same property together. here `df.groupby(some_series)` will group the records with same values of the series. Then `df.groupby(some_series).pt` only looks at the `pt` column of each group, which is the series `x` in `apply`.

Comment: Thanks, that was already helpful, yes. I think my major difficulty is still understanding how `df.groupby(some_series).pt` combined with the `apply` leads to the proper `pt_range` as a result.

Comment: print `df.t.eq(0).cumsum()` out to see what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I did this. I think, really the `apply` with a left side `groupby` is too new to me. I visualized the `groupby` already with `abc = list(df.groupby(df.t.eq(0).cumsum()).pt)` and looked only at the second component of the list entries (namely: `abc[0][1]`, `abc[1][1]`, and `abc[2][1]`). But still it remains a little bit hard to understand.

Comment: First, make sure you understand what each of the above segment is (they are consecutive segments between zeros of `t`). Now, back to the `apply(lambda x:` function, it actually takes each `abc[0][1]` and pass it to the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I have build an algorithm to break the series after each `X`. But not sure how efficient it will be.

```
# store pt to list
pt_list = df.pt.tolist()

# iterate through the list to get the index of each n after each X
md_map = {}
for idx, item in enumerate(pt_list):
        if item == "X" and idx != df.index.max():
            key = idx+1
            value = "md"
            md_map[key] = value

# map it with data frame
df["td_md"] = df.index.map(md_map)

# fill the na with td
df["td_md"] = df.td_md.fillna("td")

# create rs column from index and td_md
df["rs"] = df.td_md + df.index.astype(str)
```

I did not think abut each and every condition. But you have to build something like that.